# Referring to a variable mother Class (inheritance)

Tags: inheritance, constructor, processing

Hello StackOverflow users, I hope you can help me. Sorry for my english, it isn't my native language.

I'm new to Processing. This is what I want to do: I want to create a class called "Monitor" with these properties:
-when an instance of Monitor is called, the construnctor creates a rectangle on x, y position (defined by user), width and height defined randomly by the constructor. Height depends on width with an expression.

Then I want to create a derivate class called "OldMonitor", the properties are the same, except for the height. I want it to be 2/3 of the width of Monitor mother class, everytime an istance is called.

So this is my code:

```
class Monitor {
  float x; // pos x
  float y; // pos y
  float w, h; // width and height

Monitor(float _x, float _y) {
  x=_x;
  y=_y;
  w=random(50,100);
  h=(w*9)/16;
}

void display() {
  rect(x,y,w,h);
}
```

---

```
class OldMonitor extends Monitor {

OldMonitor(float _x, float _y) {
  super(_x, _y);
  h=(w*2)/3;
}
```

But this doesn't work as expected, because (I think) when I call super(_x, _y), w variable on OldMonitor gets a new random value, and then the expression for set the value on h depends on that new value. I want it to depend from the value generated on the Mother class, I hope this is clear to understand.

Can I realize it by still using super() constructor?

Thank you, I hope the text code is written well, I don't know how to style it here SO.

Answer (score 0):

The code works as expected.

I believe there might be some confusion with how `super()` works.
The instructions in the super constructors are almost "duplicated" within your subclass and executed: there is no connection between your subclass instance and any other instance (even of a super class)

The the super constructor to something like this:

```
Monitor(float _x, float _y) {
    x=_x;
    y=_y;
    w=random(50, 100);
    h=(w*9)/16;
    println(this,w,h);
  }
```

and notice it prints something like:

```
$Monitor@1dd41b82 85.673935 48.19159
$OldMonitor@40ceef5d 56.606354 31.841074
```

It doesn't print `Monitor@` twice.

The second issue is related to logic: even if you copy / pasted the instructions from the super class into the sublcass, the width is initialized to a random value: each time this is called it will be different.

In terms of behaviour is sounds like you want the sublcass instance to copy the width of a superclass instance and update the height using it's own aspect ratio.
Here's one way you could implement that:

```
void updateFromWidth(Monitor otherMonitor){
    w = otherMonitor.w;
    h=(w*2)/3;
  }
```

full example:

```
Monitor m1;
OldMonitor m2;

void setup(){
  size(300,300);

  m1 = new Monitor(10,10);
  m2 = new OldMonitor(120,10);
  // set w from monitor, maintaining aspect ratio
  m2.updateFromWidth(m1);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);

  m1.display();
  m2.display();
}

class Monitor {
  float x; // pos x
  float y; // pos y
  float w, h; // width and height

  Monitor(float _x, float _y) {
    x=_x;
    y=_y;
    w=random(50, 100);
    h=(w*9)/16;
    println(this,w,h);
  }

  void display() {
    rect(x, y, w, h);
  }
}


class OldMonitor extends Monitor {

  OldMonitor(float _x, float _y) {
    super(_x, _y);
    h=(w*2)/3;
  }
  // copy w from another monitor, but maintain aspect ratio 
  void updateFromWidth(Monitor otherMonitor){
    w = otherMonitor.w;
    h=(w*2)/3;
  }

}
```